# Python what is '*' used for

Tags: python, arrays

So here's my code:

```
user_input = input('What number would you like to convert?: ')
binary = []
num = int(user_input)
while num != 0:
    remainder = num % 2
    num = (num - remainder)  / 2
    binary.append(int(remainder))
print(user_input, 'in binary is: ', end='')
print(*reversed(binary), sep='')
```

Why do i have to have the '*' before printing out the array? i looked everywhere and couldn't find what it does and what its used for.

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the "splat" operator. For more information on it, see [the Python documentation on it](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

What it's basically doing is this:

```
print(reversed(binary)[0], reversed(binary)[1], ..., sep='')
```

Essentially, it uses the array elements as arguments instead of passing the array as a single argument itself.

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(lst)  # equivalent to `print([1, 2, 3])'
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print(*lst) # equivalent to `print(1, 2, 3)'
1 2 3
>>> print(reversed(lst))
<list_reverseiterator object at 0x7f4863ae4a20>
>>> print(*reversed(lst))
3 2 1
```

Comment: Is splat operator available in python 2.7?

Comment: @AerofoilKite Yes, it has existed since the very first version of Python as far as I know.

Comment: yes, even 2.6, and 3 as well.

Comment: @Doorknob冰, its giving me [SyntaxError: invalid syntax] indicating '*'

Comment: @AerofoilKite Are you running the last line of code posted in the question? If so, the problem is that `print` is not a function in Python 2.

Comment: I thought you could print tables like print(numbers), but essentially using the splat operator is referring to the elements of the table?

Comment: print *reversed(binary)  in python 2.7

Comment: @user3124289 Here, I've added a simpler example in my answer to help explain.

Comment: @AerofoilKite Yes, that doesn't work because `print` is not a function in Python 2. You could try `from __future__ import print_function`, after which it should work.

Comment: print(*lst) this is giving error.. What is the equivalent code for 2.7 using splat

Comment: Oh I see. so if I do `print([1, 2, 3])` it prints [1, 2, 3], but if i do  `print(*[1, 2, 3])` it prints 1 2 3

Comment: @user3124289 Yes, that is correct. In the first, case, you are passing one argument (the list), but in the second, you are passing three arguments (each element of the list).

Comment: @Doorknob冰, what do you mean by print is not a function in Python 2.   print lst -> this is working fine

Comment: @AerofoilKite `print` is a **statement**, not a **function**, in Python 2.

Comment: reversed returns an iterator, so `print(reversed(binary))` prints `<listreverseiterator object at 0x1047f09d0>`. Splashing it prints the binary digits.